# charge pump circuit , converting from 5v to [0.8v,1.2v]

Tags: power-supply

I am working on charge pump project. i built charge pump in ltspice, and i am getting the desired output voltage but with low efficiency.  how i can improve this by changing the parameters of the circuit?  i tried to check every parameter and its effect on the efficiency, but always i am getting trade off between the EFF and Vout:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> i built charge pump in ltspice, and i am getting the desired output voltage but with low efficiency.

The electrical efficiency of charging a capacitor from a constant voltage source through any kind of resistance (including a wire) is given by

$$\eta = \frac{\text{energy transferred to capacitor}}{\text{energy transferred to capcitor + energy dissipated}} =\frac{V_{C(0)}+V_{C(1)}}{2V_{source}}$$

where the capacitor is charged from \$V_{C(0)}\$ to \$V_{C(1)}\$ from a source of voltage \$V_{source}\$.

If a capacitor is charged from 0 V to \$V_{source}\$ through a resistance, then the efficiency is 50%. However, if the capacitor is charged from say 90% of \$V_{source}\$ to \$V_{source}\$, then the charging efficiency will be 95%. The ratio of energy that is dissipated to the energy that is stored in the capacitor is only 1:19. So, when using capacitors as energy storage, and when charging them from a constant voltage source through a resistance, it is generally advisable to keep the voltage on the capacitor near the charging voltage, to keep capacitor charging losses low.

This means, that for a charge pump to be efficient, the voltage ripple must be small. This in turn means that, to be efficient, a charge pump must have an output voltage which is related to the input voltage by a (small) integer ratio. That is, voltage doublers, voltage triplers etc., voltage inverters, voltage divide-by-two or divide-by-three etc. can be made efficient. However, voltage division by some arbitrary ratio will generally not be efficient.

Capacitor charging efficiency for "odd-ball" ratios can be improved by increasing the number of capacitors (and complexity of the circuit). However, this requires increasing the number of switching elements and consequently the switching losses. At some point, attempts to reduce the capacitor charging losses become "uneconomical" because they are balanced, or more than balanced by the associated increase in switching losses.

All this is to say that you probably will not have much luck making an terribly efficient capacitative converter from 5 V to 0.8 V or from 5 V to 1.2 V. Ignoring switching losses, a 5 V to approximately 0.8 V converter could be made by switching 6 capacitors (5/6 = 0.8333) but you will need to use MOSFETs as your switching elements and not diodes or bipolar transistors as they will make the losses too high.